# Can I update global map with only one specific pointcloud topic?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using the move base on my robot for navigation, but I have some special needs regarding how the global map and local map should be updated. The robot have two sensors for mapping, a depth camera (/point_cloud) and a laser scan (/scan). And I will publish another topic which includes the point clouds of verified obstacles (/verified_cloud). For the local map, I want to update it with the laser scan result. For the global map, I want to update it with only the verified point clouds that I published (/verified_cloud). If there is nothing published on /verified_cloud topic, I don't want the global map gets updated even the laser scan found an obstacle.

I have my yaml files like this:

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
obstacle_range: 2.5 
raytrace_range: 3.0
robot_radius: 0.25
inflation_radius: 0.5
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true


observation_sources: point_cloud_sensor

point_cloud_sensor: {sensor_frame: map, data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /verified_clouds, marking: true, clearing: false}
```

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05


observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor 

laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_range_sensor_link, data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

However, I find that the global map is still getting updated from the laser scan results. Can you help me stop the global map updating from laser scan? Thanks in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306040/can-i-update-global-map-with-only-one-specific-pointcloud-topic?/) by [mzWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/30059/mzwang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2018-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you've defined your observation sources in the root of the file, outside the local/global costmap scope (look at the indentation). Try again with those sources and the configuration of the sources in their respective scopes.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mzWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/30059/mzwang/) on 2018-10-17**:
I see. Thank you! I'll try it out tomorrow.

**Comment by [mzWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/30059/mzwang/) on 2018-10-18**:
You are correct! I need to put those sources in right scope. Thanks again!